# Duvida com o fatiamento com número negativo

Tags: python

Galera, como funciona o fatiamento de string com número negativo no python? Ele vem fatiando subtraindo dos índices?

nome = 'Fernando'
print(nome[::-2])
'onne'
eu vi que ele veio tirando a partir do índice 7 2 em 2 números. é assim que funciona mesmo ou eu estou equivocado?

Answer (score 7):

Não esta "subtraindo", ele esta "pulando", no "slice" funciona assim:

```
[start:stop:steps]
```

No seu exemplo você passou o valor de `steps` e **omitiu** os valores de **start** e **stop**, esses dois que são usados para "aparar" a `str`, nesse caso então você irá apenas "pular" certos caracteres.

Se fizer algo como:

```
nome = 'ABCDEFGHIJK'

print(nome[::-2])
```

Irá retornar:

```
KIGECA
```

Se tivesse usado numero positivo `print(nome[::2])` iria retornar:

```
ACEGIK
```

Quando você usa números negativos no **`steps`** ele irá começar o índice a partir do final

Como você omitiu o `start` e o `stop` ele vai do inicio ao fim pulando ("steps") conforme você configurou (`-2`).

Se fizer `print(nome[::3])` irá retornar:

```
ADGJ
```

Se fizer `print(nome[::5])` irá retornar:

```
AFK
```

O indice com valores positivos e negativos fica mais ou menos assim na string `ABCDEFGHIJK`:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 |
| -11 | -10 | -9 | -8 | -7 | -6 | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 |

Usando o `step` com valor `[::2]` (positivo) irá obter, se usar `[::-2]` Se vai retornar a string na ordem inversa, pois o índice começa do final:

| A | C | E | G | I | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 |
| -11 | -9 | -7 | -5 | -3 | -1 |

Usando `[::-5]`

| A | F | K |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -11 | -6 | -1 |

Com a `name='Fernando'` usando `[::-2]` você tem o seguinte (veja quais ficaram em negrito):

| F | E | R | N | A | N | D | O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| -8 | **-7** | -6 | **-5** | -4 | **-3** | -2 | **-1** |

Sendo